# Placing a bar legend right up against a ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to place a bar legend right up against a density plot.

Here are what I have tried

```
fcn = N[Array[Sin[#1*#2] &, {10, 10}, {1, 1}]];
frameLabels = {DataRange -> {{-π/2., 3 π/2.}, {-π/2., 
      3 π/2.}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {#, #} &@
    Transpose[
     Array[{{-π + π/2 #, -1. + .5 #}, {-π + π/
            2 #,}} &, 5]], 
   Epilog -> {MapThread[
      Text[Style[#1, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 
         Italic, #2], #3] &, {{"θ/π", 
        Rotate["ϕ/π", 90 Degree]}, {22, 
        22}, {{π/2., -π/2. - .7}, {-π/2. - .9, π/
          2.}}}]}};
leg = PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"], {Min[fcn], Max[fcn]}}, 
     LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkerSize -> 220, 
     "Ticks" -> {{-3.14, -π}, {0., 0}, {3.14, π}}, 
     "TickSide" -> Left, "TickLengths" -> -1.5], {.534, 0.99999}];
imagePad = {PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   ImagePadding -> {{44, 10}, {34, 10}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> 300};
appearStyle = {BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"], 
   PlotTheme -> "Classic"};
ListDensityPlot[fcn, 
 Evaluate[{frameLabels, imagePad, appearStyle, leg}]]
```

[image: try1]

When I changed the position in `Placed` to be `{.534, 1.00001}`, it looked like this:

[image]

But what I want to obtain is something like this:

[image: aim]

How could this be achieved?

I set `PlotRangePadding->False` because I don't want to have space between frame and data.

(I apologize that i did not give a code generating `fcn` in last version.)

Comment: Since you don't give us code we can run (fcn, Zak are undefined), we can't experiment with your plot. It is unlikely you will get an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried looking at the inside of the auto-generated legends and found the option `` Charting`TickSide `` which helps a bit.  I just used Column to put them next to each other, I'm sure there is a better solution though. Here's the best I got:

```
With[
 {data = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}},
 Column[{
   BarLegend[
    {"DarkRainbow", MinMax[data[[All, -1]]]},
    LegendMargins -> 0,
    LegendLayout -> "Row",
    LegendMarkerSize -> 300,
    Charting`TickSide -> Left
    ],
   ListDensityPlot[data,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0,
    ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow",
    ImageMargins -> 0,
    ImageSize -> 300
    ]
   },
  Spacings -> 0
]]
```

[image: legends]